# Using NLP to have a system learn to categorize text

Tags: python, nlp

Before I start spending a lot of time learning the concepts, I would like to know whether NLP and Python's NLTK can help me with training a system by simply feeding it text and telling it what categories are applicable.

Let's say I have about a hundred texts and I would like to categorize them across the business they describe. Is there a way to just indicate to a system per text what business is being described and then having that system more and more accurately categorize new texts in the long run?

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is a [classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) problem. To train a classification model, you will want to use either NLTK's own [NaiveBayesClassifier](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier) or one of the more state-of-the-art and customizable models from [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable).

[Here is the documentation example for NLTK's NB classifier.](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html#document-classification)

[Here is an example for the Multinomial NB classifier from scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/mlcomp_sparse_document_classification.html)

Both packages offer complete solutions to your problem. NLTK gives you all the tools to properly tokenize and lemmatize your texts yourself before feeding them to the trainer or throwing them at the trained model for classification, and it gives you the training algorithm as well. Scikit-learn does that too, with slight differences: the preprocessing part is somewhat more automatized if all you need to do is tokenize, and you have more options for training your model. [See for yourself in this example.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#working-with-text-data)

With this you should have the tools to get the job done. However, if you are new to this, here are a few tips:

1. Ensure that whatever preprocessing you do on the training texts, you do as well on the texts you will want to classify afterwards.
2. Think about acquiring a bigger training set, as 100 texts is not exactly "big data"
3. Familiarize yourself with the `pickle` module if you don't know it already, this is what will let you save a model on your computer.
4. If you choose yo use `scikit-learn`, try replacing the MultinomialNB classifier by the SVM one and compare the results. SVM is generally better.

Answer (score 2):

In short: yes, kind of. NLTK can break down raw text really well, strip out stopwords(words that occur commonly but do not give a lot of meaningful insights about the text). You can take any text, tokenize it and plot the frequency of each word. However the most common words will be "the", "of", "for", etc: stopwords. This would give you a nice overall idea but commonly not good enough. So you would need some sort of classification which also comes with NLTK. You might want to look into [this](http://www.nltk.org/howto/classify.html).

Most commonly tf-idf is what people use for this purpose. Another brilliant package that might come in handy in your case is [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) which aims to do exactly what you're looking for. And other packages have pieces that you might want to look at such as scikit-learn.

In the long run? It really depends how much resources you can throw into your project but the (relatively) simple approach is tagging: Bayes' theorem. 100 texts is a small number so using tagging for classification will likely not be extremely accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is [Topic Modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) in NLP. Python has several libraries can do this (but not NLTK, as far as I know). Check out these ones [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/), [GraphLab](https://dato.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.topic_model.create.html), or [lda](http://pythonhosted.org/lda/).